# RestKit - Relationship mapping to same entity creates infine loop

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, restkit, restkit-0.20

I need to create relationship of an entity to the same entity. Basically it is `Meetings` entity that may have any `ParantMeeting`.

[image]

This is how I am creating relationship.

```
- (RKEntityMapping *)meetingsMapping {

    RKEntityMapping *meetingsMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"DBMeetings" inManagedObjectStore:objectManager.managedObjectStore];
    meetingsMapping.setDefaultValueForMissingAttributes = NO;
    meetingsMapping.deletionPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"shouldBeDeleted = 1"];
    [meetingsMapping setModificationAttributeForName:@"updated_at"];
    meetingsMapping.identificationAttributes = @[@"id"];

    [meetingsMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
                                                          @"id": @"id",
                                                          @"title": @"title",

                                                          @"start_time": @"start_time",
                                                          @"finish_time": @"finish_time",

                                                          @"lock": @"lock",
                                                          @"location": @"location",
                                                          @"sample": @"sample",

                                                          @"deleted": @"shouldBeDeleted",

                                                          @"created_at": @"created_at",
                                                          @"updated_at": @"updated_at",
                                                          @"follow_up_id": @"follow_up_id",
                                                          @"total_topics": @"total_topics",
                                                          }];

    [meetingsMapping addRelationshipMappingWithSourceKeyPath:@"tags" mapping:[self tagsMapping]];
    [meetingsMapping addRelationshipMappingWithSourceKeyPath:@"required_participants" mapping:[self contactsMapping]];
    [meetingsMapping addRelationshipMappingWithSourceKeyPath:@"optional_participants" mapping:[self contactsMapping]];
    [meetingsMapping addRelationshipMappingWithSourceKeyPath:@"readonly_participants" mapping:[self contactsMapping]];
    [meetingsMapping addRelationshipMappingWithSourceKeyPath:@"organizer" mapping:[self contactsMapping]];
    [meetingsMapping addRelationshipMappingWithSourceKeyPath:@"parent_meeting" mapping:[self meetingsMapping]];

    return meetingsMapping;
}
```

And whenever I add relationship mapping for `parent_meeting`

```
[meetingsMapping addRelationshipMappingWithSourceKeyPath:@"parent_meeting" mapping:[self meetingsMapping]];
```

It creates an infinite loop. Is there any other way of creating relationship to same entity.

Please help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace the line that causes the recursion:

```
[meetingsMapping addRelationshipMappingWithSourceKeyPath:@"parent_meeting" mapping:[self meetingsMapping]];
```

with a direct reference to the mapping itself:

```
[meetingsMapping addRelationshipMappingWithSourceKeyPath:@"parent_meeting" mapping:meetingsMapping];
```

Comment: thanks for reply, it worked. Is it documented somewhere? I couldn't find.

Comment: A mapping being able to reference itself? Not specifically documented that I recall.

Comment: I've done it before. It seemed logical that recursive relationships can be achieved with a recursive mapping...

Comment: Yes you are right, I also thought the same that "recursive relationships can be achieved with a recursive mapping", but I couldn't guess that I should use `meetingsMapping` instead of `[self meetingsMapping]`. :)

Comment: By calling `[self meetingsMapping]` you aren't creating a recursive mapping - you are creating a never ending chain of mappings (hence the recursive call instead of recursive reference).